# How to detect "empty" elements inside a tikz \foreach statement

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, foreach

I want to define a macro that feeds its contents into a tikz `\foreach` statement, for example:

```
\newcommand\Macro[1]{ \foreach \x in {#1} {x=\x.} }
```

which is then used as `\Macro{1,2,3,4}`. Sometimes, I want to give it "empty" arguments, such as `\Macro{,,,4,5,5}`. I'd like to be able to detect the "empty" arguments and do something different in such cases. I thought that something like the following would work:

```
\newcommand\Macro[1]{%
  \foreach \x in {#1} {
    \if\relax\detokenize{\x}\relax Empty!
    \else x=\x.
    \fi 
  }
}
```

but for some reason this does not detect the empty arguments and instead produces:

[image]

I have tried many other things, such as expanding `\x` first, but I am yet to find anything that works.

Can any one see a way of doing this?

[My real code is generating a `tikzpicture` environment so I really want to use `\foreach` from `tikz.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\Macro[1]{%
  \foreach \x in {#1} {
    \ifx\x\empty\relax Empty!
    \else x=\x.
    \fi 
  }
}
\begin{document}
\Macro{,,,4,5,5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks marmot! I thought that I was probably being stupid and missing something obvious!

Answer (score 9):

The problem in the macro from the question:

```
\newcommand\Macro[1]{%
  \foreach \x in {#1} {
    \if\relax\detokenize{\x}\relax Empty!
    \else x=\x.
    \fi 
  }
}
```

is that `\detokenize` does not expand its argument and returns the two tokens `\` and `x`. This is cured by adding an `\expandafter`:

```
\detokenize\expandafter{\x}
```

The full macro:

```
\newcommand\Macro[1]{%
  \foreach \x in {#1} {
    \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\x}\relax Empty!
    \else x=\x.
    \fi 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The mandatory `expl3` answer (after noting that `\detokenize\expandafter{\x}` would be the solution):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\blankTF}{mmm}
 {% #1 = text to test, #2 = blank case, #3 = non blank case
  \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { #1 } { } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\lforeach}{O{,}mm}
 {% #1 = delimiter, #2 = list, #3 = code
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_andrew_foreach_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_andrew_foreach_seq { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\Macro[1]{%
  \lforeach{#1}{%
    \blankTF{##1}{Empty!}{$|$##1$|$.}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\lforeach[-]{a-b--\texttt{c}}{%
    \blankTF{#1}{Empty!}{$|$#1$|$.}
  }

\lforeach{, ,,4, 5 ,5}{%
    \blankTF{#1}{Empty!}{$|$#1$|$.}
  }

\Macro{, ,,4, 5 ,5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The current item in the cycle is denoted by `#1` (which has to become `##1` in the definition of `\Macro`).